# in Qbasic, How can I make my centimeter number display to one decimal place. 73.53 instead of 73.53315

Tags: qbasic

```
CLS
REM Declare Varibles
DIM MILES, YARDS, FEET, INCHES AS DOUBLE
DIM KM, METER, TINCH AS DOUBLE
DIM CM, TMETER AS DOUBLE
REM INPUT THE DATA
INPUT "ENTER THE DISTANCE IN MILES", MILES
INPUT "ENTER THE DISTANCE IN YARDS", YARDS
INPUT "ENTER THE DISTANCE IN FEET", FEET
INPUT "ENTER THE DISTANCE IN INCHES", INCHES
REM CONVERT INTO TOTAL INCHES
TINCH = 63360 * MILES + 36 * YARDS + 12 * FEET + INCHES
REM CONVERT INTO TOTAL METER
TMETER = TINCH / 39.37
REM CONVERT TO KILOMETER
KM = INT(TMETER / 1000)
REM CONVERT TO METER
METER = INT(TMETER - KM * 1000)
REM CONVERT TO CENTIMETER
CM = (TMETER - (KM * 1000) - METER) * 100
REM PRINT DETAILS
PRINT "KILOMETER", KM
PRINT "METER", METER
PRINT "CENTIMETER", CM;
```

Comment: Your example has 2 decimal places...

Comment: Go read http://faq.qbasicnews.com/?blast=RoundingNumbers, or use round() if available (QB64.org)

Comment: As this question has not been answered and in the interest of having this information available henceforth, I posted the relevant function you need.

Answer (score 1):

Classic QBasic did not have the round function so you need to bring your own.

```
FUNCTION round# (num AS DOUBLE, dp AS INTEGER)
    'WARNING: USE "#" at the end of constant values,
    'or else you will get rounding errors:
    ' "num = .45"  >> "num = .449999988079071
    ' "num = .45#" >> "num = .45"
    DIM exp1 AS LONG, num2 AS LONG
    exp1 = 10 ^ dp: num2 = num * exp1: round# = num2 / exp1
    PRINT num
END FUNCTION
```

Borrowed this from, [qbasicnews.com](http://faq.qbasicnews.com/?blast=RoundingNumbers)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can use the PRINT USING statement.

```
cm_number = 73.53315
PRINT USING "##.##"; cm_number
OUTPUT: 73.53
```

"#" - represent digits,
"." - represents the decimal point position

Click [here](https://www.qbasic.net/en/reference/qb11/Statement/PRINT-USING.htm) for a more detailed explanation.